# AndroidStudio: All classes bugged

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

[screenshot of Manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afuS6.png)
[screenshot of Android-studio with first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1gOD.png)

As you see in the image, after my PC shutdown unexpectedly, all classes (include String) and methods was bugged. 
I tried to uninstall and re-install the Android-studio but still not working (I didn't remove the sdk). 
The Android Project can run on another PC and build an apk.
Although I can clean all the Android stuff inside my PC (include sdk) and hope this can make the Android-studio will run properly again. I still want to know how to fix it in case of happening again.

1.) Project was clean and rebuild serval times.
2.) I tried start a blank new project on same PC but it had same issue
3.) reinstall the everything (studio and sdk) is not working too

======================= Solution ==========================================

I found the project can build apk in another PC. Then I try to build apk on my bugged Android-Studio and it work fine.

So I rename the Android studio project folder and move **[.AndroidStudio2.2 , .Gradle , .android]**  to other directory after re-install the Studio again... IT WORK !!!!!!! 
--fin--

Comment: This is an common error which can easily be fixed by again building gradel you also missed an import package

Comment: try disabling and reenabling the Android Support plug-in in Studio and then invalidate caches and restart?

Comment: I tried to clean and rebuild the project serval time but not working. And I add more details on my questions too :)

Comment: Please do not use "SOLVED" in your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer. You can then even accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your package name in your Manifest appears as the import of each class(consistently)

Comment: I uploaded an image of manifest maybe you could take a look. I believe that it work properly before.